# Error running openTSDB

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

Following the openTSDB guide to set up 1 cluster hbase :
http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.html 
and then
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/installation.html#id1
to run the TSD daemons , I gave the following command as specified in the docs to create tables :

```
env COMPRESSION=NONE HBASE_HOME=path/to/hbase-0.94.X ./src/create_table.sh
```

it gives the following error :

```
create 'tsdb-meta',
  {NAME => 'name', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW'}

ERROR: java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again later
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.getNamespaceDescriptor(HMaster.java:3121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:38221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Handler.run(RpcServer.java:1889)
```

and in the logs of hbase the following error shows :

```
2014-09-08 15:01:01,874 ERROR [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-localhost:51157-0] handler.CreateTableHandler: Error trying to create the table hbase:namespace
java.io.IOException: Target file:/var/folders/5c/xxxxx/T/tsdhbase/hbase-xxxxxx/hbase/data/hbase/namespace/namespace is a directory
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.rename(RawLocalFileSystem.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.rename(ChecksumFileSystem.java:425)        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.handler.CreateTableHandler.handleCreat
eTable(CreateTableHandler.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.handler.CreateTableHandler.process(CreateTableHandler.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

your command was:

env COMPRESSION=NONE HBASE_HOME=***path/to/hbase-0.94.X*** ./src/create_table.sh

this is copied from the documentation. Where it says "path/to" it is expecting you add fill in the path to your hbase-0.9X folder.

For example. I installed hbase under my local user which is called drmclean. 
The path is therefore:

/home/drmclean/hbase-0.98.6.1-hadoop2/

Note that again in the command that you wrote, hbase-0.94.X means "insert your version number in here instead of the X.

use tab-autocomplete to ensure that the path that you've given the command is the correct path.

Comment: I had entered a path. I thought that was obvious as the error is while creating the tables. Had the path not been correct it wouldn't go as far as attempting to create the table!

Comment: Is HMaster definitely running?
Use "jps" to check wither HMaster is running correctly, you should be able to start it with /path/to/hbase-0.97etc/bin/start-hbase.sh